# How to handle `UIAlertController` properly if the source view gets changed?

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I created an UIAlertController as below:

```
let menu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

menu.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = someView!
menu.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = someView!.bounds
```

It works fine until I rotate the device. (iPad only, because for iPad, the UIAlertController shows a popover at a position depending on `sourceView` and `sourceRect`)

When I rotate the device, the position/size of `someView` are changed by some other module. Therefore, there are some warnings about contraints:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
```

Although it's just warning, I still hope to know what's the proper way to handle  `UIAlertController` when the source view gets changed?

EDIT:
Logs for the constraint warnings:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fac14c672f0 UIView:0x7fac14c994c0.width == 19>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fac14c95260 UIView:0x7fac1483b430.width == 300>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fac124f8520 _UIAlertControllerView:0x7fac14c41cc0.width == UIView:0x7fac14c994c0.width>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fac14c09ac0 _UIAlertControllerView:0x7fac14c41cc0.width >= UIView:0x7fac1483b430.width>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fac14c95260 UIView:0x7fac1483b430.width == 300>
```

Comment: What constraints are wrong exactly? Could you show us the code the produces the error?

Comment: what do u want to achieve any way

Comment: @Sulthan please see EDIT part

Comment: @Sulthan the code is just any standard code to create UIAlertController. I just added some more info in my question because this problem only happens with iPad. For iPad, the UIAlertController shows a popover and its position/size is based on the sourceView & sourceRect. And when an iPad is rotated and if the source view is changed somehow, how to handle this situation properly?

Comment: @JoeHuang On iOS 5 and iOS 6 this was happening with popovers too, usually we had to hide the popover on rotation and then show it again when the rotation has finished.

Comment: @Sulthan how do you hide it? something like `theController.view.hide = true` will do? And I have to track if the controller is opened or dismissed?

Comment: @JoeHuang Nope, we just dismissed popover before rotation and presented it again after rotation. We were using `UIViewController` subclass that was tracking presented popovers and rotation events.

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks. If it is an answer, I will accept it. Looks like it is the only way?

Answer (score -1):

try  using following  It works

```
 @IBAction func actionContinueToPay(sender: UIButton) {
        let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: "Select payment method", message: "Select the payment method first", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        let cashOnDeliveryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cash On delivery", style: .Default, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            // self.serviceCallSaveOrder()
            self.serviceCallSaveOrder("No Token",STATUS: self.STATUS_COD)

        })



        let walletAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Pay by Card", style: .Default, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            self.serviceCall_GetcardInfo()

        })

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            print("Canrcelled")
        })
        optionMenu.addAction(cashOnDeliveryAction)
        optionMenu.addAction(walletAction)

        optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.presentViewController(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```